# Open Office tutorials

Tags: openoffice, documentation

I've been teaching the Open Office suite to adults. I've found some tutorials online, but I don't like them very much.

There is always the possibility of doing one myself, but instead I could translate a good tutorial to portuguese, my first language.

So, does **anyone knows of a good open office tutorial**?

Thanks

Comment: Not to be ranting, but while you're teaching you may want to use the right name: OpenOffice.org or OOo. Not OpenOffice, not Open Office. http://www.openoffice.org/FAQs/faq-other.html#4

Comment: For anyone who didn't follow @Arjan's link, `OpenOffice` is owned by another company and that's why using it is wrong. I figured I'd mention that in case people thought @Arjan was being a pompous **** :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First, I'd suggest getting the [pt version](http://pt.openoffice.org/) for your students. Next, (if you don't mind reading Brazilian-Portuguese) visit http://www.broffice.org/ for a wealth of [documentation and information](http://www.broffice.org/docs) em portuguese.

Furthermore, if your students understand english, or you are capable of translating material, you could look at the many tutorials at http://www.tutorialsforopenoffice.org/, and http://www.learnopenoffice.org/index.htm

Comment: Thanks Jonathan. They already have the PT-pt version and the dictionary. Those are the first and second hits if I search google. I dont like them very much, was trying to find something better.

Answer (score 2):

You could just get a MS office tutorial, even though microsoft stinks, open office is still alot like it.

Answer (score 0):

I've written one [here](http://www.filefactory.com/file/cdd6378/n/LO_2011-Aug.pdf). It's on LibreOffice - which is almost the same.